# Как в vk_api можно назначить администартора в чате?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Пишу бота на питоне, который будет работать от паблика в чате паблика, надо сделать так чтобы он мог назначать и убирать админов.

Comment: Увы, но когда я сталкивался с этой проблемой - это было невозможно. Сейчас проверил api и, судя по всему, это всё ещё не реализовали.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на просторах интернета скрытый метод **`messages.setMemberRole`**

Параметры:

1. role, (роль)
2. peer_id, (беседа)
3. member_id (айди участника)

Посмотрите **[тут](https://github.com/vknet/vk/issues/1031)**